# How to make a custom controller like the app "Figure" by properllerhead?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm recently playing with the music producing app "Figure". It has wonderful UI and UX. There are four disks in the first screen, where I can tap and drag to change the values.

Does anyone know how they made this function? Is it achieved by UIGestureRecognizer or UISlider? It would be better if you can provide some sample code here.

[image]

Comment: The four discs, do they move up and down on finger drag? Which disc are those anyways? Ones with Kick, Hats? or the ones on the blue lines?

Comment: @iosDev82 The discs don't move up or down. The discs are the ones with Kick, Hats. When you tap the disk and drag down, the number in the center will decrease. When you tap the disk and drag up, the number will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of which demonstrates how this can be achieved with CAShapeLayer.

```
@interface MyDraggableSlider ()

@property (nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *outerPathShape;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentAvailableOptions;

@property (nonatomic) CATextLayer *textLayer;

@end


@implementation MyDraggableSlider

static const CGFloat kDefaultLineWidth = 20;
static const CGFloat kDefaultAngleSeparationBetweenStripes = 10;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _maximumOptionsAvailable = 8;
        _currentAvailableOptions = 0;
        [self createShape];
        [self createPath];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)createShape
{
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = kDefaultLineWidth;
    shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    CGRect textFrame = CGRectInset(shapeLayer.bounds, shapeLayer.lineWidth, shapeLayer.lineWidth);
    textFrame.size.height = 40;
    textFrame.origin.y = (self.bounds.size.height - textFrame.size.height ) * 0.5;

    self.textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    self.textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.textLayer.backgroundColor = nil;
    self.textLayer.frame = textFrame;
    self.textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;

    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.textLayer];
    self.outerPathShape = shapeLayer;
}

- (void)createPath
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.outerPathShape.lineWidth * 0.5, self.outerPathShape.lineWidth * 0.5);
    CGFloat gapAngle = [self radianFromDegree:kDefaultAngleSeparationBetweenStripes];

    CGFloat angleForEachStripe = (2 * M_PI - gapAngle * self.currentAvailableOptions)/ self.currentAvailableOptions;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(rect) * 0.5;


    CGFloat currentAngleOffset = gapAngle;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    if (self.currentAvailableOptions == 0) {
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < self.currentAvailableOptions; i ++) {
        CGFloat startAngle = currentAngleOffset;
        CGFloat endAngle = currentAngleOffset + angleForEachStripe ;

        UIBezierPath *stripePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                                  radius:radius
                                                              startAngle:startAngle
                                                                endAngle:endAngle
                                                               clockwise:YES];
        [path appendPath:stripePath];
        currentAngleOffset = endAngle + gapAngle;
    }

    self.outerPathShape.path = path.CGPath;

    if (self.currentAvailableOptions == 0) {
        self.textLayer.string = @"";
    } else {
        self.textLayer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.currentAvailableOptions];
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));


    CGPoint touchPoint = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self];

    CGPoint vectorFromCenter = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - center.x, touchPoint.y - center.y);
    CGFloat normalizedValue = sqrt(vectorFromCenter.x * vectorFromCenter.x + vectorFromCenter.y + vectorFromCenter.y);
    CGPoint normalizedVector = CGPointMake(vectorFromCenter.x / normalizedValue, vectorFromCenter.y / normalizedValue);

    CGFloat angle = atan2(normalizedVector.y, normalizedVector.x);
    CGFloat currentRotationOffset = angle + M_PI;
    if(isnan(currentRotationOffset)) {
        self.currentAvailableOptions = 0;
    } else {
        self.currentAvailableOptions = currentRotationOffset / (2 * M_PI / self.maximumOptionsAvailable) ;
    }
    [self createPath];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (CGFloat)degreeFromRadian:(CGFloat)radian
{
    return 180 / M_PI * radian;
}

- (CGFloat)radianFromDegree:(CGFloat)degree
{
    return M_PI / 180 * degree;
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyDraggableSlider *slider;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 200) * 0.5, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 200) * 0.5, 200, 200);
    self.slider = [[MyDraggableSlider alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slider];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `UITapGestureRecognizer` & `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gestures to required objects.

Objects can be any like `UIImageView`,`UILabel`,`UIButton`,etc.

You can add selector to both gesture & it will be called accordingly. For complete understanding of the Gesture refer this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Sample code is also there so if you would like to try directly then you can try that as well.